All My Pages Dynamically Generated When Fetching Data in the Root Layout?
I am fetching data in the main layout at the root level to generate the navbar for my application. However, when I try to build the project, I notice that all pages, including static pages like the Contact Us and FAQs pages (which should be static), are being marked as dynamically generated. This is unexpected because these pages don't involve any dynamic content or data fetching.
The issue seems to stem from the way the data for the navbar is being fetched at the root level. I suspect that this might be causing Next.js to treat all pages as if they require server-side rendering or dynamic content, even though they are supposed to be static.
I'm not sure if this is related to how the data is fetched in the main layout or if there is some configuration I am missing that is affecting the behavior of static pages. Could this be an issue with Next.js' automatic static optimization, or is there something in my setup that is causing all pages to be dynamically generated?
How can I fix this so that only the necessary pages are dynamically generated, while keeping the static pages (like Contact Us and FAQs) truly static during the build?
View the website ui here
